# Puppeteer scraping attempt always ends in undefined value

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

Simple code, should work, but it doesn't.

```
const puppeteer = require ('puppeteer');

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless:false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'
});
await page.goto(url)

const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h1');
const txt = await el.getProperty('txt')
const srcText = await txt.jsonValue()

console.log(srcText)
}
scrapeProduct('https://getbootstrap.com/')

//Same result on other urls as well.
```

I've also tried to querySelector instead of xPath, that worked in some cases, it would log the first value of the node as expected, but then querySelectorAll on the same element would again return "undefined". I've looked everywhere, but simply can't find the solution.

Comment: I think if you changed `[el]` to `el` you'd be fine

Comment: Also is there a reason you're not using `page.setUserAgent`?

Comment: I did what Syntax suggested and it worked. I didn't know what page.setUserAgent did cos am totally new to puppeteer. But I made my script by now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i do it this way

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function scrapeProduct(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    "user-agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36",
  });
  await page.goto(url);

  // wait for elements defined by XPath appear in page
  await page.waitForXPath("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h1");

  // evaluate XPath expression of the target selector (it return array of ElementHandle)
  const headings = await page.$x("/html/body/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/h1");

  // prepare to get the textContent of the selector above (use page.evaluate)
  let textContent = await page.evaluate((el) => el.textContent, headings[0]);

  console.log(textContent);
}
scrapeProduct('https://getbootstrap.com/')
```